# How to select all form field elements using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have been looking for this on stack, but couldn't find a complete jQuery script.

Basically I'm looking for a short, simple jQuery script to select all options with a link.

Need help.

```html
<fieldset class="usp-fieldset usp-fieldset-default">
<select name="usp-taxonomy-country[]" required="required" data-required="true" multiple="multiple" class="usp-input usp-input-taxonomy custom-taxonomy usp-select">
<option value="">Please select..</option>
<option value="11">United States</option>
<option value="12">Canada</option>
<option value="13">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="14">Australia</option>
<option value="15">New Zealand</option>

</select>
</fieldset>

<a href="#">(select all countries)</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('select.usp-select option').prop('selected', true);`

```js
function selectAll() {
  $('select.usp-select option').prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="usp-fieldset usp-fieldset-default">
  <select name="usp-taxonomy-country[]" required="required" data-required="true" multiple="multiple" class="usp-input usp-input-taxonomy custom-taxonomy usp-select">
    <option value="">Please select..</option>
    <option value="11">United States</option>
    <option value="12">Canada</option>
    <option value="13">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="14">Australia</option>
    <option value="15">New Zealand</option>

  </select>
</fieldset>

<a href="#" onclick="selectAll();">(select all countries)</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your time and effort, Tartarus! thanks again!